# The name of this type of matrix

Tags: matrix

whats the name and the rules of a matrix thats like this.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   X   .   .   .   X   .
2   .   .   .   X   .   .
3   .   .   .   .   X   .
4   .   .   .   .   .   .
5   .   .   .   .   X   .
6   X   .   .   .   .   X
```

and it gets turned into this.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   1   1   1   2   2
2   1   1   1   2   3   3
3   1   1   1   2   4   4
4   1   1   1   2   4   4
5   1   1   1   2   5   5
6   2   2   2   3   6   7
```

Comment: I don't know.  Where has this come from?

Comment: Look up "dynamic programming".

Comment: How does A turn into B in the first place?

Comment: I second Kerrek SB: It looks surprisingly similar to a dynamic programming implementation of say, a spellchecker.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the rule seems to be that the value of each element corresponds to the number of 'X' that are both above and to the left.

Comment: Don't think so. line 2 column 4: value is 2 but the number of X above and on the left is 3.

Comment: @Saphrosit: I mean all X that are both above and to the left.

Comment: It seems to work if you count also the X in the element itself and if the comparison is not strict: (above or in the same line) && (on the left or on the same column)

Comment: @Saphrosit: Yes, that's what I meant.  I was just too lazy to type it all!

Comment: Thanks I get it now, now I am only missing the name but its not that important.